# Align multiple divs to bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

I want align 3 divs at the bottom of parent with `100%` height.

I tried:

```
parent {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

but doesn't work.

It should work even if you change the size or resolution of the window.

example: [image]

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do this using the new [Flexbox Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

simply apply

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content:flex-end;
```

For the container `div` as shown below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#box1 {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
#box2 {
  background: orange;
}
#box3 {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='box1' class='box'></div>
  <div id='box2' class='box'></div>
  <div id='box3' class='box'></div>
</div>
```

[More about flexbox @ css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to specify the relative heights of the parent and content, and the `div` with `display:table-cell` must be in an element with `display:table`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Y2mP8/1/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
}
div div {
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
div div div {
    display:block;
    height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use divs vertically instead of horizontally, you can try the code below

```css
.s_div{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxnHM.png)